# Best practices in implementing multi-tenancy in a roo app

Tags: spring-roo

I am developing a simple CRUD app using roo. User auth is done using database tables 
(Ref: http://roosbertl.blogspot.com/2010/06/using-spring-security-database-in.html)

I want to limit a "normal" user to only reading, searching, updating records created by him/her.

Is this possible directly with roo? What is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to have all queries written so that they are identified by the user id (joined to the users table), then have your DAO automatically pull the user's id from the UserContext and add it to the criteria/query if the user does not have an ADMIN role.